# Troble with updating the list box

Tags: excel, vba

I have Created a excel user form with three Combo box and list box with 3 columns.

When user selects a value from drop down list and click Add button it will be displayed in the list box - Done

When user selects a item in the list box it will again displays in drop down list - done

But when user selects the item in the list box and click update button its calling the ListBox
_click ()  function, I dont want it to call the listbox_click function

PLease help.  updating the code

Code for adding value from drop down list to list box

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
Call lstValues.AddItem(AddPpayTierOption(cboPpayTier.Value))
lstValues.List(UBound(lstValues.List), COL_BRAND) = cboBrandTier.Value
lstValues.List(UBound(lstValues.List), COL_GEN) = cboGenTier.Value
End Sub
```

when clicks the item in the list box it will display the value in drop down list

```
Private Sub lstValues_Click()
Dim I As Long
cmdEdit.Enabled = True
cmdRemove.Enabled = True  
If lstValues.ListIndex <> -1 Then
    For I = 0 To lstValues.ColumnCount - 1
        If I = 0 Then
        cboPpayTier.Value = lstValues.Column(I)
        Else
        If I = 1 Then
        cboBrandTier.Value = lstValues.Column(I)
        Else
        If I = 2 Then
        cboGenTier.Value = lstValues.Column(I)
        End If
        End If
        End If
    Next I
End If
```

End Sub

when user click the update button code.

when it goes to **lstValues.Column(j) = cboPpayTier.Value** line its calling the lstValues_Click() function I don't want code to call that function. Please Help

```
Private Sub cmdEdit_Click()
Dim j As Long
Dim var As Variant
 If lstValues.ListIndex <> -1 Then
        For j = 0 To lstValues.ColumnCount - 1
            If j = 0 Then
            lstValues.Column(j) = cboPpayTier.Value   
            Else
            If j = 1 Then
            lstValues.Column(j) = cboBrandTier.Value
            Else
            If j = 2 Then
            lstValues.Column(j) = cboGenTier.Value
            End If
            End If
            End If
        Next j
    End If
End Sub
```

please let me for more clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

1. Use `Application.EnableEvents = False` to disable event processing.  And `Application.EnableEvents = True` to re-enable.  Note, this disables *all* event handling, so place it either side of code that would otherwise trigger an event you don't want.
2. Declare a global flag.  Set it just before code that will trigger an event you don't want.  In the Event `Sub` itself, examine the flag, and exit if it's set.  Reset the flag either on the other side of the event triggering code, or in the event `Sub` itself.  Doesn't stop the event firng, but stops it executing code you don't want.

As requested, example of option 2

In a standard module, at the top (just after `Option Explicit`), add this code

```
Global InhibitEvent As Boolean
```

In your code

```
' Somewhere in your code,
' when you are about to execute some logic that will trigger an event
InhibitEvent = True

'... event triggering logic here

InhibitEvent = False
```

In the Event `Sub` that you don't want to execute (eg a listBox Change event)

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
    ' Look for Event Inhibit
    If InhibitEvent Then Exit Sub

    ' rest of event code here

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain option 2 how to do it .... if you give the code that would be really helpful

Comment: @ chris thanks a lot works great...I have a another question....when I select the value in drop down list i want to check if taht value is already available in ith list box , if so then i should not update those value... basically i want only unique values update in list box

Comment: Glad to help.  BTW etiquette here on SO is that if you find this or any answer helpful, you should accept it.  (click the tick)

Comment: its Done. Apologies newbie in SO... if you find time please let me for unique values in list box... this code should be in Private Sub cmdAdd_Click() module that where we add values from drop down to list box thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try using a List as the data source of list box. When updating, first put datasource of listbox null then equal to List